# Using Matlab's fmincon to find optimal parameter of SDOF system having discrete white noise input

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, optimization, matlab, mathematical-modeling

I am trying to use Matlab's fmincon function to find the optimal value of $k$ for the following ODE, which represents a mass-spring system,
$$m\ddot{x}(t)+kx(t)=f(t),$$
where $f(t)$ is taken to be constant amplitude white noise. The cost function is taken to be absolute maximum displacement of the mass, that is, $\max_\limits{t}(|x(t)|)$.

The issue I am having is that `fmincon` takes a very long time to find the optimal value when using a white noise input. When using a sinusoidal input, `fmincon` finds the optimal value relatively quickly. Note that this is just an illustrative example of a problem I'm experiencing with a more complicated ODE, that is, even with the complicated ODE, having a sinusoidal input the optimal value is found relatively quickly.

First let's generate the white noise input and save it into an `.mat` file,

```
stepsize = 0.01;
tgm = 0:stepsize:10;
fgm = randn(numel(tgm),1);
save('gm.mat','tgm','fgm')
```

The code is broken into three parts:

The objective function and loading the discrete input:

```
function cost = objfunc(para)
tstart = 0;
tfinal = 10;    % sec

load('gm.mat','tgm','fgm')
options = odeset('RelTol',1e-8 ,'AbsTol',1e-8 );

z0 = [0 ; 0];

[t,z] = ode45(@(t,z) sdof(t,z,para,tgm,fgm), [tstart,tfinal], z0,options);

cost = max(abs(z(:,1)));
end
```

The ODE:

```
function dz = sdof(t,z,para,tgm,fgm)
dz = zeros(2,1);
k = para;
m = 1
f = interp1(tgm, fgm, t, 'linear');

dz(1) = z(2);
dz(2) = -(k/m)*z(1) + f/m;
end
```

Calling `fmincon`:

```
para0 = 0.1;
lb = 0;
ub = 1;
para = fmincon(@objfunc, para0, [], [], [], [],lb, ub);
```

I'm pretty new to using Matlab's Optimization Toolbox so I'm not entirely sure if I'm approaching this problem correctly, or if I should code the white noise differently or input it in a different place.

Thanks for any help or feedback!

Comment: In my opinion, the problem is that you load your mat file each time you are computing the cost function. Consider using persistent parameters or anonymous functions. Note also that for your problem the ```fminbnd``` seems to be more pertinent.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I will experiment with either keeping the inputs as persistent variables or using anonymous functions. I did see ```fminbnd```, but the more complicated ODE will optimize over 3 parameters and so I'll need to use ```fmincon``` eventually.

Comment: As a follow up question, would using an anonymous function created using the ```fit``` function on the generated white noise then importing the object through fmincon possibly lead to faster convergence?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Surprisingly, but the problem is not in `load`. When I run your code with a profiler, it takes 460 seconds, where 396 seconds are spent for `interp1`, 2808319 calls, that is 141 ms per 1000 calls.

If you open the code of this function, you will find that it makes a lot of things to parse your inputs, then it creates a `griddedInterpolant`, and then it interpolates. Since we know that we always call it with the same   `tgm` and `fgm`, let us create the `griddedInterpolant` on our side, and then pass it to the function as an argument. Ok, now the code with the profiler takes 178 seconds (125 seconds without profiling), where interpolation takes 71 seconds for the same 2808319 calls, that is 25 ms per 1000 calls, more than 5 times faster.

Creating anonymous functions does not change a lot in this case, but I have also updated the code to show how it works.

The function that creates a handle for the cost function:

```
function obj_fh = get_objfun(tgm, fgm)

    data_set = griddedInterpolant(tgm,fgm);

    tstart = 0;
    tfinal = 10;    % sec
    z0 = [0 ; 0];

    options = odeset('RelTol',1e-8 ,'AbsTol',1e-8 );

    obj_fh = @(para) objfun(para);

        function cost = objfun(para)
            [~,z] = ode45(@(t,z) sdof(t,z,para,data_set), [tstart,tfinal], z0,options);

            cost = max(abs(z(:,1)));
        end
end
```

The function that implements the ode

```
function dz = sdof(t,z,para,data_set)
    dz = zeros(2,1);

    k = para;
    m = 1;
    f = data_set(t);

    dz(1) = z(2);
    dz(2) = -(k/m)*z(1) + f/m;
end
```

The main script

```
para0 = 0.1;
lb = 0;
ub = 1;

load('gm.mat','tgm','fgm');
objfunc = get_objfun(tgm, fgm);

para = fmincon(objfunc, para0, [], [], [], [],lb, ub);
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, it was very helpful, and definitely sped up the computation time. I have one follow up question though, in the ```get_objfun``` function, you set ```obj_fh=@(para) objfun(para)```, where ```objfun``` is defined just below. My question is, where does ```obj_fh``` get ```para``` from? Is it provided by ```fmincon``` some how?

Comment: The object ```obj_fh``` if a function handle. It is a pointer (handle) to a function that takes one input ```para``` and returns ```cost```. The function ```get_objfun``` creates a local workspace with local variables, e.g., ```data_set```, and then defines the function ```objfun```, which operates on this workspace. The pointer to the function can be then used to compute the cost using the previously defined workspace.